# Upgrading a composer installed Typo3 LTS 8 to LTS 9.5

Tags: typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I am trying to understand how to upgrade a LTS8 installation installed with

```
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution myProject ^8
```

to LTS 9.5.

When I follow the documentation and do

```
composer require typo3/cms-backend:^9.5 typo3/cms-core:^9.5 typo3/cms-extbase:^9.5 typo3/cms-extensionmanager:^9.5 typo3/cms-filelist:^9.5 typo3/cms-fluid:^9.5 typo3/cms-frontend:^9.5 typo3/cms-install:^9.5 typo3/cms-recordlist:^9.5 --update-with-dependencies
```

I get

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. 

Problem 1
   - typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor v8.7.19 requires typo3/cms-core 8.7.19 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v8.7.19] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
   - typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor v8.7.19 requires typo3/cms-core 8.7.19 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v8.7.19] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
   - typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor v8.7.19 requires typo3/cms-core 8.7.19 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v8.7.19] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
   - Installation request for typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor (locked at v8.7.19, required as ^8.7.10) -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor[v8.7.19].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Shouldn’t my fresh installation not be all v8.7.19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no direct way on this major update. I finally ended up exporting the pagetree of my 8.7 installation as well as the db, created blank 9.5 installation with all extensions, imported the pagetree and imported the db. Since I only used major ext like georgringer/news and bootstrap_package I had no major prolbmes